# Kneser theorem about the Klein bottle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, klein-bottle

I know that in $1923$ H. Kneser showed that a continuous flow in a Klein bottle without singular points has a periodic trajectory. The original article is [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01498385), but does anyone know another old or new proof of this result? I would really like to read this result, I tried to do it from your original article but the language is too complicated for me. I searched on the internet but found almost nothing about the proof.

Comment: Nice question: if no one answers it here, I advice you to post it also on the [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net), our sister site.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thank you very much, I'll wait for the time to end and if I don't get an answer I'll post it on the other side...

Comment: also at https://mathoverflow.net/q/423108/11260